# How to calculate the probability of multiple people winning multiple games?

Tags: probability

If for example I have $100$ people playing a coin toss game. Every person has $5$ coin tosses. If a person manages to successfully call each of the $5$ coin tosses they win.

So I know to calculate for 1 person's odds, its just $0.5^5 = 1/32$ ($3.125\%$), but if I want to calculate the odds of, say, $42$ people correctly guessing all $5$ in a row, how do I figure that out?

Comment: By means of [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution). There are $100$ independent experiments that can succeed or fail, and all have the same chance to succeed. To be found is $P(X=42)$ and the parameters are $n=100$ and $p=2^{-5}$.

Comment: This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 1):

This will follow a binomial distribution with parameters $n=100$ and $p = \frac{1}{32}$.

Now we know that if $X \sim B(100,\frac{1}{32})$,

$$P(X = k) = \binom{100}{k} \left(\frac{1}{32} \right)^k \left(1-\frac{1}{32} \right)^{100-k}$$